# Sub-pages in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

it's probably obvious because i didn't find anyone who talk's about it:
there is module/controller/action - but what if the website depth is much deeper
?
for example:

```
module/controller/action/sub-page(s)/sub-sub-page(s)/and so on..
```

is routes is the **correct** way for it?:
puting the action for the module/controller/action/**sub-page** in the controller and making a route for it.

Am i missing something or this is the way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Sub-page is a actually not a Sub-page but still rendered by an view script that refers to an controller/action.

Your logic would mean that after the view script is again a controller/action but this is not correct and would violate MVC structure.

Read [**Zend Framework & MVC Introduction**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html).

Comment: you mean: module/controller/sub-page instead of module/controller/action/sub-page?

Comment: I am a bit confused of your definition of subpage. The MVC approach is to have a controller with action and then view scripts. If you have something that is deeper in your website logic then the actual view script then this is just a website design issue, for zend framework this is still controller/action -> view script, so you just would create another action and viewscript at the same level

Comment: so, this is the way to do it: home(module)/category(controller)/page(action)/sub-page(another action in the same controller) and put a route for the sub-page?. i didn't understand what is the problem with the site logic. this is still MVC - the qustion is if i can make sub actions and sub controllers or not.

Comment: you got it ;) no sub-controllers, no sub-actions

Comment: I confess that I always felt the same: why should three levels - module/controller/action/m even with params - be considered sufficient for a deep site-structure like `http://exmaple.com/products/accessories/jewelery/rings/with-stone/diamond/some-cool-ring/`? But I've come to see that using routes and params, you can cover it all with just the three levels. In fact, in principle, modules are just a convenience and the MVC pattern works fine with just controller, action, and parameters.